# Can "a" be used with a superlative adjective?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles, superlative-degree

The Wikipedia article for [Drum Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_machine) contains the phrase

> *an earliest* fully transistorized rhythm machine

Is this grammatically correct? Is it any different from the phrase

> *an early*, fully transistorized rhythm machine

I always assumed that superlatives may only be used with "the" but never "a" or "an".

Comment: It's *just **a first** impression*, but my feeling is your "rule" is a bit OTT.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem grammatically correct to me.  Either it's "THE earliest" or "AN early" drum machine but not "an earliest" drum machine.

Comment: The superlative is often used for emphasis, and in this context _earliest_ means _from the earliest times_.

Comment: @JohnLawler good point, now that you mention it I can think of other examples of this type of usage.  This particular one still sounds clumsy to me.  The construct may be logically incorrect, but not necessarily gramatically incorrect.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's plenty clumsy, all right. But so are the vast majority of questions and examples we get here; par for the course, I fear.

Comment: ... but not parest.